# Spring: `RequestScope` vs `RequestContextHolder`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets

I am writing a Spring Boot service and wanted to include some form of `RequestContext` available to the controllers that might store things like the authenticated user and a request id. However, I see multiple approaches:

1. Use an `@RequestScope` bean
2. Use `ServletRequest.setAttribute`
3. Use Spring `RequestContextHolder`

What are the tradeoffs between these approaches?

Comment: Is this a reactive or mvc context? Not an answer, but I suggest you to look at RequestMapping method arguments: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html . It is in the class javadoc as bulleted list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, `RequestScope` is the Spring *magic* way. It internally uses a `RequestContextHolder` which in turn depends on `ServletRequest.setAttribute`.
Said differently, the *Spring way*, is IMHO `RequestScope`. `RequestContextHolder` makes sense if you prefer limit the magic of Spring annotations.
Finaly, `ServletRequest.setAttribute` is still lower level, and should mainly be used if you want the code to be compatible with a non Spring application.

Moreover, for the first two ways, Spring uses a thread scoped object to store a reference to the request context, which allows the programmer to access the beans even in methods that do not explicitely receive the Request object.